# Use of \subsubsection in doxygen file .dox

Tags: doxygen, sections

I am trying to use a subsubsection, however it is not showing.

```
/// \section sec Section
///    [TODO] Section Info
/// \subsection subsec Subsection
///    [TODO] Subsection info
/// \subsubsection subsubsec SubSubsection
///    [TODO] Subsubsection Info
```

Comment: I just tried it with version 1.8.9.1 and I did see the information (placed it in a .h file for testing, including a \file command as there is nothing else in the file).

Comment: I am using Doxygen version 1.8.6. It is part of the documentation file .dox where a \page is defined.

Comment: I tried with doxygen 1.8.6 and default Doxyfile. I added the statement: /// \page mp My page as the first line of the file aa.dox and ran doxygen 1.8.6 and I see the section., subsection and subsubsection.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong somewhere in the page

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the type of error you found?